# I'm trying to insert the value of "seconds" into the "timeArr" array, but the first value insertet somes out as 0

Tags: reactjs

Here i define seconds and timeArr

```
const [spaceEventCounter, setSpaceEventCounter] = useState(0);
const [isRunning, setIsRunning] = useState(false); // isRunning = true -> secondsCounter = running
const [timeArr, setTimeArr] = useState([8.55, 9.55, 10.55, 11.55, 12.55]);
const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
```

this useEffect starts and stops a counter if isRunning = true/false

```
useEffect(() => {
let interval;
if (isRunning) {
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    setSeconds(seconds => Number((seconds + 0.01).toFixed(2)));
  }, 10);
} else {
  clearInterval(interval);
}
  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [isRunning]);
```

the problem occurs when setTimeArr is run within the handleKeyUp function in the third if statment

```
  useEffect(() => {
  const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
  if (event.code !== "Space") return;
  if (spaceEventCounter === 0) {

    setSpaceEventCounter(1);
  }
  if (spaceEventCounter === 2) {
    setIsRunning(false);
    setTimeArr([...timeArr, seconds]);

    setSpaceEventCounter(3);
  }
  };
  const handleKeyUp = (event) => {
  if (event.code !== "Space") return;
  if (spaceEventCounter === 1) {
    setIsRunning(true)

    setSpaceEventCounter(2);
  } else if (spaceEventCounter === 3) {

    setSpaceEventCounter(0);
  }
  } ;
  document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
  document.addEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp);
  return () => {
  document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
  document.removeEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp);
  };
  }, [spaceEventCounter]);
```

I dont know what to try :(

Comment: Wouldn't the `spaceEventCounter`, which depends on and changes `spaceEventCounter`, keep adding event handlers? I'm not sure how state changes from handlers might be batched, but it seems sketchy. It's kind of hard to follow what could be happening here, or what its actual purpose is.

Answer (score 0):

What I see is that you declare your functions inside `useEffect`.

This `useEffect` hook has `spaceEventCounter` as dependency.

In other words, every time `spaceEventCounter` changes, you redeclare your functions and add event listeners, while you really need to add the event listeners once the component is mounted.

I would try using the last `useEffect` with an empty dependency array.